# NULL statement doesn't fill the empty spaces in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, null

I'm having trouble with NULL statement in SQLITE. I added NULL in cases there is no info to be filled, but once I run the code the IDE throws an error.

```
CREATE TABLE tenants (        
    Apartment_Number INT(4),
    Family_Name  VARCHAR(8) NULL,
    Sur_Name  VARCHAR(14) NULL,
    Home_Number  INT(4),
    Mobile_Number int(10),

    PRIMARY KEY (Apartment_Number )
);      


INSERT INTO  tenants           
VALUES
      (101,,,201,0544431263),
      (102,,,202,0544431263),
      (103,'Shklobin','marta',203,0544431263),
      (104,'arman','charles',204,0544431263);

SELECT * FROM tenants;
```

The empty spaces are where I hope the IDE will fill with NULL values.
The error I receive:

> Error: near line 12: near ",": syntax error.

If I remove the `NULL` statement, the IDE runs the code with no errors.

Comment: Either specify just the columns you're actually adding, or use `null` instead of an empty argument.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) indicates that

> The default value of each column is NULL.

The default behavior is also to *allow* NULL in each column.  The behavior only changes if `NOT NULL` and/or `DEFAULT ...` constraints are specified.  You should get the same error whether or not you have the *lone NULL keyword* as shown in the question code.  My testing shows that the following does not suppress the error as implied in the question--in other words, the following change results in the same error.

```
    Family_Name  VARCHAR(8),
    Sur_Name  VARCHAR(14),
```

The following alternative INSERT statements will work:

```
INSERT INTO tenants
    (Apartment_Number, Home_Number, Mobile_Number)
VALUES
    (101,201,0544431263),
    (102,202,0544431263);

INSERT INTO tenants 
VALUES
    (103,'Shklobin','marta',203,0544431263), 
    (104,'arman','charles',204,0544431263);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO  tenants           
VALUES
      (101, NULL, NULL,201,0544431263),
      (102, NULL, NULL,202,0544431263),
      (103,'Shklobin','marta',203,0544431263),
      (104,'arman','charles',204,0544431263);
```

Comment: Hey C,
Doesn't adding the 'NULL'  manually defeat the purpose ?  I would very much like the process to be as automatic as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Uhh... what purpose?  I thought your purpose was to get the data into the database, and the SQL syntax (at least interpreted by sqlite) requires explicit NULL literals.  sqlite apparently doesn't interpret missing data as NULL.  But I'm also not sure what part of "automatic" you are implying, because any script or language that allows you to build the `INSERT INTO` statement will certainly be able to replace empty / null / missing values with a literal `NULL` string.  So I think the answer is "No"... it does not defeat the purpose.

Comment: If you mean copy and paste data into "the IDE" and build it manually, then once again I don't know what you mean by "purpose" since most programming and database IDE's are very general purpose and contain other tools for preparing text.  If you need, use the Find & Replace functionality to change ",," to ",NULL," and similar replacement for NULLs at the end of the string, etc.  To my knowledge there is no general purpose tool that will magically format data into appropriate SQL without some scripting and manual tweaking.  If you ever get data formatted perfectly, lucky you!

Comment: No problem.  I hope I didn't sound rude.  Nothing is wrong with learning, I just like to be direct.  But if I did not quite answer the question, then please elaborate and perhaps I could give further hints or make the process a little smoother.

Comment: Oh, and I take back my one comment.  I have used tools that are actually really good at interpreting raw data and transforming it into other formats including databases.  But those tools were rather expensive and provided to me on the job.  In the mean time, I almost always must massage data to get it from one source into another destination.  So my "lucky you" comment was not meant to be snarky, it really was a congratulation for getting data that is already formatted nicely if that ever is the case. :)

Comment: C, Thanks very much. Your comments were not rude, in fact i understood allot from them. I was looking to build the database in the most automatic means as possible.but that was my misunderstanding. .